# Can't get to add JS to front via $this->load->view

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I'm developing a module for OpenCart 3.x and I'm trying to insert some JavaScript code into website's front via `$this->load->view()` method but cannot get it to work, as the JS code doesn't appear in the DOM.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

**/catalog/controller/extension/module/mymodule.php**

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleMyModule extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->language('extension/module/mymodule');

        $this->load->model('checkout/order');
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');
        $this->load->model('design/layout');
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        $data['js_output'] = "Some JS output"; 

        return $this->load->view('extension/module/mymodule', $data);
    }
}
```

**catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/mymodule.twig**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('This is working!");
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Add an external javascript file via controller like this:

```
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/my-external-script.js');
```

But if it's a block of javascript code, you don't need to edit controller file, just add it to your view file (twig or tpl):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("This is working!");
</script>
```

Finally you may need to clear caches (vqmod, ocmod, twig etc ...).

EDIT

If you want to prepare your javascript code in the controller, follow this:

**controller**

```
$data['js_output'] = 
'<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("This is working!");
</script>';
```

**Twig**

```
{{ js_output }}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've wrote in the post. I've added the JS to .twig file and it is not working.

Comment: I can't see `addScript` in your code. also did you clear  caches?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared all the cache. Also, the `addScript` method won't work in my case so that is not an option for me.

Comment: I have tested your edited answer but sadly it is not working :(.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed the issue. It was a problem with the `install()` method not correctly inserting and loading the design/layout (`$this->model_design_layout->getLayouts()`).

If your module needs to insert a layout into the `layout_module` table, make sure you have the correct `layout_id`, `code`(which must be your module name), `position` (i.e: '`content_bottom`') and `sort_order`(which often times is > 90).